# Why is this loop prematurely exiting when removing JSON objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a simple JSON array.

```
{
  "food" : [
    {
      "name" : "apple"
    },
    {
      "name" : "orange"
    },
    {
      "name" : "peach"
    },
    {
      "name" : "carrot"
    },
    {
      "name" : "lettuce"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to remove all but keep one, the removal for-loop pre-emptively exits.

```
String itemToKeepsName = "carrot";
JSONArray list = wrappedFood.getJSONArray("food");
JSONObject addThisItemBack = null; // be ready to make a new space in memory.

println("number of items in list: " + list.length()); // prints 5.
int found = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
  if(addThisItemBack.equals(list.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"))) {
    found = i;
    addThisItemBack = new JSONObject(list.getJSONObject(i).toString());
  }
}

if (found >= 0) { // found at index 3.
  println("number of items before removeall loop: " + list.length()); // prints 5.
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    println("removed item: " + i); // prints 0, 1, 2. 
        list.remove(i);
  }

  println("adding item: " + addThisItemBack); // {"food":["name":"carrot"}]}
  list.put(addThisItemBack);

}
```

But this results in:

```
{
  "food" : [
    {
      "name" : "carrot"
    },
    {
      "name" : "lettuce"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  "food" : [
    {
      "name" : "carrot"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make sure the list is completely emptied before I add an item back? Did I overlook something obvious? Is this something esoteric to JSON manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you remove an element, the `list` shrinks. This

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    println("removed item: " + i); // prints 0, 1, 2. 
    list.remove(i);
}
```

Means `i` quickly passes the length of the `list`. I would suggest [`List.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--) like

```
list.clear();
```

or an `Iterator` with [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--)

```
Iterator<JsonValue.ValueType> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    JsonValue.ValueType value = iter.next();
    println("removed: " + value);
    iter.remove();
}
```

Be aware of the note from the linked Javadoc: *The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.*

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, I don't know why I didn't notice that earlier. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the accepted answer, I realized my issue is as easy as capturing the number of items BEFORE starting the loop.

```
if (found >= 0) { // found at index 3.
  int countOfItemsToRemove = list.length(); // do this
  println("number of items before removeall loop: " + countOfItemsToRemove); // prints 5.
  for (int i = 0; i < countOfItemsToRemove; ++i) {
    println("removed item: " + i); // prints 0, 1, 2. 
        list.remove(i);
  }

  println("adding item: " + addThisItemBack); // {"food":["name":"carrot"}]}
  list.put(addThisItemBack);

}
```